# How can i store uri generated by using mongodb-memory-server in process.env?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to store the database URI in process.env
Below is the sample code. Here I am returning the URI instead, I need to store it in process.env

```
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require("mongodb-memory-server");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    promiseLibrary: Promise,
    useFindAndModify: false
};
const mongoServer = new MongoMemoryServer();
module.exports = async function (conn) {
        const uri = await mongoServer.getUri();
        console.log(`[MONGO] --- ${uri} ---`);
        require("../model")(conn);
        await mongoose.connect(uri, options)
        return uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need `process.env.MONGOURI = uri`

The code will be something like this:

```js
const uri = await mongoServer.getUri();
process.env.MONGOURI =uri

//Rest of the code
```

Note that `MONGOURI` is a random name, you can choose other if you want.

If you do

```js
console.log("ENV URI = ",process.env.MONGOURI)
```

In another part of the code, you will get the value saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
module.exports = async function (conn) {
        const uri = await mongoServer.getUri();
        console.log(`[MONGO] --- ${uri} ---`);
        require("../model")(conn);
        await mongoose.connect(uri, options)
        process.env.uri= uri ;
}
```